# String.Substring() crashes with certain inputs

Tags: c#

I trying to split a string with Substring(), and I am having a problem I keep getting crashes with certin values.The problematic lane is(according to the "debugging" i tried):

```
string sub = str.Substring(beg,i);
```

and the whole code is :

```
    static void Prints(string str)
    {
        int beg = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == '*')
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                //Console.WriteLine("before");
                string sub = str.Substring(beg,i);
                //Console.WriteLine("after");
                beg = i+1;

                if (sub.Length % 2 == 0)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(sub.Length/2);
                    int n = sub.Length / 2;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", sub[n-1], sub[n]);
                }
                else
                {
                    int n = sub.Length / 2;
                    Console.WriteLine(sub[n]);
                }
```

The eror happens when the input is :

```
hi*its*
```

thats the output:

```
h i


Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at _39.Program.Prints(String str) in D:\12\39\Program.cs:line 36
   at _39.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\12\39\Program.cs:line 13
```

I know there might be a better way using split() but I still want to understand what cause the eror.
Thanks in advance
Doron.

Comment: It is `string Substring(int startIndex, int length)`, but not `string Substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)`.

Comment: Why don't you use string.Split instead? (By the way, the second parameter of Substring is the number of characters to retrieve, not the position of the last character to retrieve)

Comment: We dont have string.split in our textbook so I tried to figure how to solve the question without split.Anyway thanks for the answer, it turns out that was the problem.

Comment: The first time you enter the if, and get to Substring(), i==2 and beg==0.  Then beg becomes 3 (i+1).
The second time you enter the if, i == 6, beg == 3.  You are trying to get a substring that starts a position 3, and has length 6.  But at this moment, there is not more string, because is the last '*'.

Comment: The error message clearly indicate the problem. Before wasting people time (and yours writing a question), you should read the error message. The error message say **Index and length must refer to a location within the string**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not subtracting the distance you are into the string from the overall length.
If you look at the debug output you will find that:

```
str.Substring(3, 1) = "i"
str.Substring(3, 2) = "it"
str.Substring(3, 3) = "its"
str.Substring(3, 4) = "its*"
str.Substring(3, 5) = // Error! You're beyond the end of the string.
```

So clearly you are attempting to pull (in your example) 6 characters from the string starting at position 3.  This would require an input string with total length 10 or more (as substring is Zero Index based). Your input string is only 7 chars long.

Try tokenizing your string.  As soon as you try manually tokenizing using indices and counting things go wrong.  Tokenizing is a god send :)
Good Luck!